# Strange effect with sizeof

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

The following code works as intended:

```
template <typename T>
inline char* Utils::PushData(char* destination, T data)
{
    memcpy(destination, &data, sizeof(data));
    destination += sizeof(T);
    return destination;
}
```

However, when I use this:

```
template <typename T>
inline char* Utils::PushData(char* destination, T data)
{
    memcpy(destination, &data, sizeof(T));
    destination += sizeof(T);
    return destination;
}
```

the model I'm building gets messed up. Why would this happen? Surely `sizeof(T)` and `sizeof(data)` should be the same, right? Or have I misunderstood what `sizeof` actually gets the size of?

**edit**

I wasn't really too bothered with this one, just thought it was odd. I am using `memcpy` because I need to ensure the my data is packed with out padding, I also trust my self (the only person who will use this code unless I do decide to take it further) to know to only use it with basic types, and I don't even call this function directly, I would call a function that would take data in a format that makes more sense from the calling location. I would call this template function using something like...

```
inline char* Utils::PushXYZ(char* destination, float xValue, float yValue, float zValue)
{
    destination = PushData<float>(destination, xValue);
    destination = PushData<float>(destination, yValue);
    return PushData<float>(destination, zValue);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(T)` and `sizeof(data)` should indeed be the same.  What specifically makes you think they weren't?  (Can you narrow it down from "the change broke something"?)

Comment: where did destination get allocated?

Comment: Even the first code snippet uses sizeof(T) (`destination += sizeof(T)` line).  It would be easier to answer the question if we knew which data type causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely sizeof(T) and sizeof(data) should be the same, right? Or have I misunderstood what sizeof actually gets the size of?

That's not necessarily the case. Consider this one:

```
template<typename T> void f(T data);
int main() { f<char[1]>(0); }
```

This will yield `sizeof(char[1])` when applied to `T`, and `sizeof(char*)` when applied to `data`. Depending on your code, you may have weird instantiations of your template, which could have causes such a case.

Comment: Gosh. So if you don't use `iterator_traits` in your algorithms, people can do `char g[] = "hi there"; std::for_each<char[2]>(g,g+8,Whatever());`. That's ... special.

Answer (score 2):

Using memcpy in c++ is a very bad idea.

Do you know what will happen if you memcpy the object of a class that has virtual methods? What will happen if you memcpy classes like vector and string? If you are lucky - core dump.

btw how did you use that function? What went wrong? etc
If possible post a minimal compilable example

Comment: Okay, I agree memcpy of objects which have private heap storage is bad, but I don't see how virtual methods play into this (aside from making it less clear whether an object has private heap storage or not).  Usually, having virtual methods just means there's one or more vtbl pointers in there, which is set at construction, points to a constant table, and doesn't change over an object's lifetime.  I don't see how copying these pointers (since they don't point to heap-allocated blocks) breaks things.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: More appropriately, if you memcpy sizeof(T) bytes, any type that derives from T will be sliced in a really bad way, and the virtual functions will immediately crash, as the dynamic type is :T but the data is only T.

Comment: @Mike @Dead: In simple terms, non-POD types cannot be treated as a sequence of bits and doing so leads to UB.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in the debugger if sizeof(T) == sizeof (data), which it should normally.  Not 100% sure what happens if `T` is a reference type, but I think `sizeof(U&)` would not be the same as `sizeof()` passed a parameter of U& type.

Comment: If you pass a reference to that function, the sizeof will return correct value (unless buggy compiler). It is easy to create the example from the code in the original post (just print the size of data and T to the standard output).

Answer (score 1):

That `memcpy()` isn't buying you anything.  Use an array or vector.

You're advancing the `destination` pointer by `sizeof(data)`.  If you use an array, the distance from one entry to the next is `sizeof(data)`.  No difference.

If there is no padding at the end of `data`, then there's no wasted space.  If there is padding at the end, it's part of the data structure, and will be included in the `sizeof()`.  If you want to save memory, look at compiler options to pack information in a class.

If you're using a standard type, like the `float` in your edit, then there is no wasted memory in either way of doing this.

You have not provided any example of how you tested, or what results you got, even in your edit, so nobody's going to be able to help you with that.